# Kotlin: Can't return a derived type

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following kotlin function from an android project. I'm trying to return either a Movie or TvShow 'Fragment' that both derive from the base android 'Fragment' class. This code worked when it was java code but once converted to Kotlin - it no longer works. The error I'm getting is a type mismatch on the MovieFragment because it is type 'MoviesFragment' and not 'Fragment?'.

---

```
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
        when (position) {
            0 -> {
                val moviesFragment: MoviesFragment = MoviesFragment()
                return moviesFragment
            }
            1 -> {
                val tvShowFragment: TvShowFragment = TvShowFragment()
                return tvShowFragment
            }
            else -> {
                return null
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to be ok, try to match imports of Fragment in both classes. 
It should be the same in all subclasses, For example `import android.app.Fragment` or `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`